# VueJs How to call a modal once a day?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good afternoon) Help please. How to make the modal pop up once a day when the site loads. I have 2 options with localstorage and cookie, but I don't know how to make the logic correct.

project link
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-torvalds-e315y?file=/src/App.vue:2283-2284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I think this should work

```
// modalService.js
const STORAGE_KEY = "LS_LAST_UPDATE";

const getStorageValue = () => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY));
  } catch {
    return "";
  }
};

const setStorageValue = (value = "") =>
  localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(value));

const dateIsOld = () => {
  const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

  return getStorageValue() !== today;
};

const updateDate = () => {
  setStorageValue(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
};

export { dateIsOld, updateDate };

export default {
  dateIsOld,
  updateDate,
};
```

and in your vue component you do something like this

```
import { dateIsOld, updateDate } from "./path/to/modalService.js"
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    //this.runModalTimer()
    this.showModal = dateIsOld()
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.showModal = false;
      updateDate()
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: It looks like it works
thank you so much

I have a question will the modal window pop up next day?